# How to create an archive (tar, 7z, zip) on the fly?

Tags: rust, zip, actix-web

I have an actix-web server and want to have an endpoint where user can download a dynamically generated archive (tar or zip or 7z).
How can I do that?

All the examples I saw either generated archive in memory (not an option, can be big) or generated a temp archive file.

I want to give archive data as it appears.

Comment: Consider using [`async_zip`](https://docs.rs/async_zip/latest/async_zip/write/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether it's easily possible for zip files. The compression usually requires a lot of back-and-forth between data that's already written and new data.

If you want to build a tar file, there's the `tar` crate which provides a [`Builder`](https://docs.rs/tar/latest/tar/struct.Builder.html) class. The builder wraps a `Write` implementation which ultimately receives the archive data.

So in order to glue it together with actix-web, you'll probably need to write a struct which implements both `Write` and the `futures::stream::Stream<Item=Bytes, Error=Error>` trait.

Probably easiest would be to have something built on [`poll_fn`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/fn.poll_fn.html) from the `futures` crate - one just needs to be aware that not too much data must be kept in memory because it risks DoS attacks on the server by requesting but not actually reading the data and keeping the connection open.

Comment: `zip` uses either no compression or DEFLATE, which has a pretty small window (32k), it's the same alg used by gzip. `zip` puts the central directory at the end of the file, so it requires the entire thing for "proper" decoding, but when encoding there is no issue with streaming individual entries, keeping track of the various items and offsets, and generating the central directory after all the individual entries have been emitted.

Comment: Couldn't tell you whether rust's zip crate(s) support this use-case, but the archive format absolutely does.